# JDK 8 javadoc @propertyGetter,@propertySetter and @propertyDescription warnings

Tags: tags, java-8, javadoc

JDK8 Javadoc give me lots of the following warning messages:

```
warning - Tags @propertyGetter, @propertySetter and @propertyDescription 
can only be used in JavaFX properties getters and setters.
```

source code does not use any of these tags.

Where do the messages come from?

JDK 7 works fine without these warnings.

Answer (score 1):

There is a closed [OpenJDK bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8185424) for that exact error message, stating that it arose on Linux using Java 8u131 when running **javadoc** for a class with a method like this:

```
public boolean isProperty() {
    return false;
}
```

The user also reported (like you) that this was not an issue with Java 7. That bug was closed since the error could not be reproduced. I also tried to reproduce the problem using 8u152 on Windows 10, but everything worked fine.

However, [an open and related bug report was then created by the user](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1706969), suggesting that the issue was related to an Ubuntu build of 8u131.

I'm guessing that this is no longer an issue for you, but if it is:

- If you still have the problem, can you reproduce it by running **javadoc** against the trivial class detailed in [that original bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8185424)?
- What version of Java and what Operating System are you using?
- Does your source have any methods named **getProperty()**, **setProperty()** or **isProperty()**?

Answer (score 0):

The error can be reproduced using 8u172, on both Windows and Linux, by adding the option `-Xdoclint:none`. If you use the option `-Xdoclint:-accessibility,-html,-missing,-reference,-syntax` you disable all the checks for problems in javadoc comments but without the warning about JavaFX.

[OpenJDK bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8185424) doesn't mention that option.